# Filter Visual Studio (or ReSharper) Intellisense by type

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, intellisense

Is there a way to filter the Visual Studio Intellisense by type?

Example: when I'm using a control such as Infragistics' XamDataGrid there are a seemingly endless number of fields, properties, events and methods.  I'd like to be able to filter the intellisense by type, i.e., show me only events.

I've found these suggestions on the JetBrains site, but no resolutions:

- [RSP-27166 - Filter Events/Properties/Methods in IntelliSense](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-27166)
- [RSP-101619 - Enhanced control over items displayed in completion popups (intellisense window)](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-101619)

Comment: FYI: Those links throw 404's

Comment: Is this not supported yet? I mean we are in 2016-2017,   this is very basic feature....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such feature.
I miss is as well....
(Same as possibility to navigation window listing properties / methods / events only)

Re question: in same cases [Smart Code Competition](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Smart_Completion) can help.

Comment: Shame since this is a feature that has been requested since 2006.